# Cannot find global type 'CallableFunction' error in tsconfig.json file

Tags: typescript, nearprotocol, assemblyscript

Basic project.

Everything was working fine when I was using NPM, but to get asbuild, I had to use yarn. But I started to get the error message in my tsconfig.json file.

```
Cannot find global type 'CallableFunction'
Cannot find global type 'CallableFunction'
```

tsconfig.json file

```
{
"extends": "../node_modules/assemblyscript/std/assembly.json",
"include": [
  "./**/*.ts"
]
```

}

Here are my dependencies in package.json.

```
  "devDependencies": {
"asbuild": "^0.2.0",
"assemblyscript": "^0.23.1",
"near-sdk-as": "^3.2.3",
"typescript": "3.1.6"
},
```

Not sure what is causing this issue.

Comment: Your TypeScript version is *severely* out of date and doesn't include the built-in type `CallableFunction`.

Comment: I am inferring details from the post; although the original poster is using an outdated typescript version, VSC by default will use bundled typescript for tsserver (which in VSCinsiders is 4.9.3 at the moment). As assemblyscript/std/assembly.json (extended in tsconfig.json) specifies "noLib", CallableFunction/NewableFunction are not defined as they are defined in lib/es5.d.ts in TypeScript. If the posters TS version was relevant there wouldn't be an error as AssemblyScript does not use CallableFunction/NewableFunction in the codebase.

Comment: Any updates on this ? Facing the same issue on a clean AssemblyScript project (ie. simply running `npx asinit .` creates a folder `assembly` with a `tsconfig.json` that raises this issue)

Comment: @OscarSjöstedt see here for the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75697581/cannot-find-global-type-callablefunction