# Cannot find global type CallableFunction

Tags: typescript, webassembly, assemblyscript

It is a Basic Assembly script project. But I facing this error message in my tsconfig.json file.

```
{
    "extends": "assemblyscript/std/assembly.json",
    "include": [
    "./**/*.ts"
] 
}
```

It is my package.json

```
{
   "devDependencies": {
   "assemblyscript": "^0.27.1"
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You error seems to be described in this AssemblyScript [issue](https://github.com/AssemblyScript/assemblyscript/issues/2646). The stated workaround from there is this:

> For now, you can disable these newer types by changing your project's
> tsconfig.json and setting strictBindCallApply to false like this:
>
> ```js
> {
>   "extends": "assemblyscript/std/assembly.json",
>   "include": [
>     "./**/*.ts"
>   ],
>   "compilerOptions": {
>     "strictBindCallApply": false
>   }
> }
> ```